# Spring boot with Java 10 modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-9, activiti, java-10

I am trying to move my spring boot + activiti app to Java 10. Following is the pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.10</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

module-info.java

```
open module testmod {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.se;

    exports com.test;
}
```

On build I see multiple errors like this

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.el from both juel.api and tomcat.embed.el
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
```

Found multiple related questions, and as suggested, I tried excluding commons-logging from both dependencies but it is not working.

Is there any right way to resolve this issue?

Comment: It sure looks like you need [Simple Logging Facade for Java](https://www.slf4j.org/news.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I did not get that. slf4j dependency already added via spring-boot

Comment: I'm interested in getting Activiti 7 working with JDK 9 and 10, so I'm interested if you manage to get 6 working with it. Feel free to join our Gitter channel if you want to discuss how we can get this done: https://gitter.im/Activiti/Activiti7?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link